# Convert ppt to pdf using libreoffice: duplicate slides and "javaldx: Could not find a Java Runtime Environment!"

Tags: java, libreoffice, pdf

I convert a ppt file into a pdf file, by

```
$ libreoffice --headless --invisible --convert-to pdf 1.ppt 
javaldx: Could not find a Java Runtime Environment!
Warning: failed to read path from javaldx
convert /tmp/test/1.ppt -> /tmp/test/1.pdf using filter : impress_pdf_Export
Overwriting: /tmp/test/1.pdf
```

1. What do the first two lines about `javaldx` in the output mean?

   Will that cause some problem? I am not sure if the created pdf file
   has some problem.

   How shall I solve the problem?
2. One thing I found is that the command created duplicated slides of
   the original ppt file in the output pdf file, although in some
   slightly different look. For example: [the original ppt file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8e1expeq809bd7h/1.ppt?dl=0) has
   19 slides, but [the output pdf file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/v8nzc6fm03kkywe/1.pdf?dl=0) has 38 pages with the first
   19 pages for the 19 slides and the last 19 pages for the same 19
   slides again with a different look.

   Is it because of the `javaldx` related error and warning? How can I avoid the duplicated pages for the same slides?

Thanks.

---

Update:

```
Ubuntu 16.04

$ libreoffice --version
LibreOffice 5.1.6.2 10m0(Build:2)

$ java --version
java 9-ea
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9-ea+171)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9-ea+171, mixed mode)
```

I have never changed my libreoffice after it was installed.

---

Update:

I just installed the latest libreoffice, and when I convert ppt to pdf, the javaldx not found warning is gone, but the output pdf file still has duplicated pages for the slides (see the link I gave earlier). So how shall I avoid the duplicated pages in the output pdf file?

```
$ libreoffice5.4 --headless --invisible --convert-to pdf 1.ppt 
convert /tmp/test/1.ppt -> /tmp/test/1.pdf using filter : impress_pdf_Export
Overwriting: /tmp/test/1.pdf
```

Comment: I don't have java installed. I am using Ubuntu 16.04.3 and LibreOffice 5.4.1.2 from ppa. I don't know if updating to 5.4 will solve your problem.

Comment: How can I add the ppa  and install from there?

Comment: In a terminal enter: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa` and enter your password when prompted. Then update the computer as you normally do.

Comment: Thanks. While I was typing the last comment, I just manually downloaded the latest deb files from libreoffice official website and installed from the deb files. Will adding the ppa work with the installed libreoffice just installed? Or shall I uninstall the libreoffice that I just installed.?

Comment: I don't know. Do you now have two versions of Libreoffice installed? If so, the ppa will update the default version.

Comment: I just installed the latest libreoffice, and when I convert ppt to pdf, the javaldx not found warning is gone, but the output pdf file still has duplicated pages for the slides (see the link I gave earlier). So how shall I avoid the duplicated pages in the output pdf file?

Comment: I downloaded your ppt and converted to pdf using the command you used. I didn't get the duplicated pages in the pdf. No idea why you are getting them or how to fix it.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any other difference between the output pdf files that you and I got, besides the duplicated pages? For example, how about the bookmarks/outlines?

Comment: I don't see any difference See the screenshot https://imgur.com/a/pTPAw.